# Fastest way to get vector of parents in a tree graph

Tags: r, igraph

Given a tree graph like this:

```
library(igraph)
g <- sample_pa(1000, power=1, directed=FALSE)
nodes <- V(g)[-1] # exclude root node since it has no parent.
```

What is the *fastest* way to get the parent of every node?

I currently use this:

```
parents <- unlist(adjacent_vertices(g, nodes, mode = c("out")))
```

but it is actually one of my code bottlenecks since I need to do this for thousands of graphs (around 50 vertices each).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's try this on a smaller graph so we can see what's going on:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(144)
g <- sample_pa(20, power=1, directed=FALSE)
plot(g)
```

[image]

In your graph each node has exactly one parent, so I would expect a vector of length `n-1` for a graph with `n` nodes (19 in this case and 999 in the example you provided). You can be obtained efficiently from the edge list, selecting the first column:

```
get.edgelist(g)[,1]
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 2 4 1 6 1 9 6 2 6 2 1 1 8 7
```

Visually we can confirm that the parent of node 2 is node 1, the parent of node 3 is node 1, the parent of node 4 is node 2, the parent of node 5 is node 3, and so on.

This will be much more efficient than the approach using `adjacent_vertices` for a large graph. For instance, on your graph of size 1,000, it is about 1,700 times faster:

```
set.seed(144)
g <- sample_pa(1000, power=1, directed=FALSE)
nodes <- V(g)[-1] # exclude root node since it has no parent.
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(get.edgelist(g)[,1], unlist(adjacent_vertices(g, nodes, mode = c("out"))))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                                  expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
#                                  get.edgelist(g)[, 1]     84.558    110.891    262.4235    125.497    169.947   9673.282   100
#  unlist(adjacent_vertices(g, nodes, mode = c("out"))) 303523.390 350459.141 455860.3464 444960.802 528314.593 754882.895   100
```

Further, your example returns a vector of length 1,965 in this example even thought the graph has 999 edges. This is because most edges are returned twice by your code, once for each endpoint.

If you actually wanted all 1,965 values returned exactly as they are in the code you provide in the question, you still could speed up the operation considerably (750 times) using `get.edgelist`:

```
match.op.output <- function(g) {
  el <- get.edgelist(g)
  el <- rbind(el, el[,2:1])
  el <- el[order(el[,1], el[,2]),]
  el[el[,1] != 1,2]
}
all.equal(match.op.output(g), unlist(adjacent_vertices(g, nodes, mode = c("out"))))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(match.op.output(g), unlist(adjacent_vertices(g, nodes, mode = c("out"))))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                                  expr        min          lq       mean    median          uq        max neval
#                                    match.op.output(g)    541.416    585.5115    692.889    652.18    744.0785   1437.427   100
#  unlist(adjacent_vertices(g, nodes, mode = c("out"))) 382952.446 429673.4950 507641.095 486633.23 554715.5570 749883.994   100
```